# How to navigate the user to different page after logging in?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package for the user to login.
I want to take the user to different page once logged in instead of remaining in the same page.

Is it possible to be done through `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package?

If not, what other alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function [`Meteor.onLogin`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin), it could be used on both client and sever.